# Is it possible to create a body for the spirit of a sentient magic item?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, published-adventures, out-of-the-abyss, intelligent-magic-items

In the *Out of the Abyss* campaign which I'm currently playing in, the party found a magic sword ([Dawnbringer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dawnbringer), a Sun Blade with additional properties). The sword has its own personality, spirit, or soul - whatever you'd call it. Anyway, the group didn't really need the sword so we just kinda ended up talking to it a lot. In our last session, we thought it would be an idea to try give this sword its own body.

I thought maybe with the *clone* spell we could create a body and then try transfer the soul of the sword into it, but I don't believe this is possible.

Is there a way we can create a body for Dawnbringer, maybe with some sort of spell or other magic item?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: I, personally, am baffled at the idea of a party in OotA not having a use for Dawnbringer. (Light source, d8 finesse weapon that can be used with only shortsword proficiency, radiant damage, bonus damage vs. undead, +2 attack and damage...and Dawnbringer has an extra feature on top of that.) Do you guys just not have anyone at all that fights in melee?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### That is entirely in the hands of your DM

The game term for a magic weapon that can talk is a Sentient Weapon. These are described beginning on page 214 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*. However there is little to guide their exact nature:

> Such an item might be possessed, haunted by the spirit
>   of a previous owner, or self-aware thanks to the magic
>   used to create it.

So, depending how the sword has been made (as determined by your DM) there could be a soul trapped in it, which could have a soul to be restored to its body by spells like [*true resurrection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-resurrection). However from the description of Dawnbringer (*Out of the Abyss* page 222) it seems it was merely forged and given consciousness and therefore has no soul to be transferred or rescued.

There might still be a way for you to do this though, but it hinges on a lot of DM fiat. The closest solutions in RAW is probably creating a golem, a homunculus, or  use [*awaken*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/awaken) and letting Dawnbringer be wielded by and controlling the made/awakened creature.

Creating a golem (see Manual of Golems on page 180 of the DMG) is expensive; starting at 50,000 gp and 60 days for a [flesh golem](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/flesh-golem) and the obtained creature is probably more powerful (CR 5) than a DM would let you have.

Creating a homunculus using [*create homuncolous*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-homunculus) a 6-th level Wizard spell from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* is a possibility cheaper option. However RAW it only creates a tiny creature which is going to have a hard time with a longsword. How to scale that up to something that can be useful to Dawnbringer is up to your DM. This is costly on the hit-points on the caster though if you want the homunculus to have more hit points.

For *awaken* you would need to find/make something that could wield Dawnbringer if it was sentient which might be tricky, although personally I would allow a lightsaber-wielding-sentient-bush on 'rule of cool' or maybe rather 'rule of silly'.

However your DM might be persuadable to let you build something lesser (animated armor springs to mind) to create such a vassal. However even if constructing a lesser construct for the sword it would still be perfectly reasonable for you DM to require the investment of a *lot* of time and money (or other exotic resources and maybe make an adventure out of obtaining those) for essentially adding another creature to your party, as increasing that number can warp combat significantly and make it harder to balance such (an thus harder to make fun). This latter point is likely why the game's core resources (i.e. the books) do not readily provide a solution for you.

Comment: The [UA Sidekicks](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/sidekicks) might be worth reading for the purpose of balancing an additional companion.